# Cannot create a bucket in S3 using ruby aws-sdk v2

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

When trying to create a new bucket in an S3 account using the ruby aws-sdk version 2, I always get the following exception:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `location_name' for nil:NilClass
  index_members_by_location_name at /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.21/lib/seahorse/model/shapes.rb:283
...
```

I initialized the S3 client with the correct region and correct credentials. The following is part of my sample code:

```
...
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: region, credentials: credentials)

bucket = s3.create_bucket(bucket: 'mynewbucket')
puts bucket.inspect

# List the available buckets
puts "Available buckets:"
resp = s3.list_buckets
resp.buckets.each do |bucket|
    puts bucket.inspect
end
```

One note is that the code that lists the buckets works fine.
Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I even added this code in order to list the objects in an existing bucket, and it throws the exact same error as above:

```
resp = s3.list_objects(bucket: 'existingbucket')
resp.contents.each do |object|
  puts "#{object.key} => #{object.etag}"
end
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that is actually failing since I do not see anything showing the method `index_members_by_location_name`.

Comment: Basically, this line: `bucket = s3.create_bucket(bucket: 'mynewbucket')` is the one throwing the error. That `index_members_by_location_name`seems to be part of the Seahorse class of the aws sdk api.

Comment: Tracking the source is difficult because of it's dynamic nature. Have You tried `Aws::S3::Bucket.new("mynewbucket",client: s3).create` to see if it has the same result? It should as this seems to be a simple wrapper for the same method. I am just interested to know.

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky. Just tried your code and it throws the same exception.

Comment: Yeah I figured it would seems very strange since looking at the source `members` is an `Enumerator` and yields `member_name` (as a symbol) and `member(member_name)` which should be a `Shape` and if it cannot locate a reference to the member it should raise here. Have you reached out to Amazon.

Comment: @engineersmnky, as a matter of fact I posted the issue I'm getting in the official chat of the gem. I'm waiting for an answer but in the meantime I will try with the v1 gem to see if it works fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is caused by a bug in JRuby 1.7.4 and how it handles the enumerable #inject and #each.with_object. Upgrading JRuby will resolve this issue.